# PowerShell use for windowstyle hidden parameter

Tags: powershell

Hy,

how to hide powershell script window in windows 10 task scheduler application?

This is how I try:

-executionpolicy bypass "c:\script\teszt.ps1" - windowstyle hidden

but this doesn't work
the program starts, the powershell window remains on the screen in the foreground

Comment: Put -windowstyle before the script name: `powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -windowstyle hidden "c:\script\teszt.ps1"`

Comment: For answers please look Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802127/how-to-run-a-powershell-script-without-displaying-a-window) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75255390/run-powershell-encoded-command-single-vbs-file-no-third-party-tools)